# how to get map object in event?

Tags: leaflet, events

I add a listener to a button

```
 L.DomEvent
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault)
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', this._onMarkerChange);
```

And then I want to move map by panto function.

```
_onMarkerChange: function (){
    this._handlingClick = true;
    for (var opt in this) {
        if(this[opt].selected)
        {
            var lat = this[opt].getAttribute( "data-lat" );
            var lon = this[opt].getAttribute( "data-lon" );
            this.L.Map.panTo( new L.LatLng( lat, lon ) );
            break;
        }
    }
     this._handlingClick = false;
},
```

It has an error --Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
How should I do? pass map object into this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not specify the 4th argument in [`L.DomEvent.addListener`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domevent-addlistener) (the "context"), then `this` inside your callback  will refer to the DOM element that triggered the event, i.e. what is referred by `selectList` in your code.

Then `for (var opt in this)` will loop through all `selectList` DOM properties, and `this.L.Map.panTo` will expect that `L` is referenced as a property of `selectList`. I do not think you can use it as-is either.

Now if you pass your `map` as 4th argument, `this` will refer to it. You can still access your DOM element by taking an argument `event` with your callback and looking for `event.currentTarget`.

```js
this._onMarkerChange = function (event) {
    var dataset = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    var lat = parseFloat(dataset.lat);
    var lon = parseFloat(dataset.lon);
    this.panTo( new L.LatLng( lat, lon ) );
}

L.DomEvent
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault)
    .addListener(selectList, 'click', this._onMarkerChange, map);
    // map as 4th argument will be the context (this) in the callback.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/49/

I am unsure about what object you want to refer to by using `this` within your callback (`_onMarkerChange`). As said above, `this` will refer to the DOM element (`selectList`) if you do not specify the 4th argument in `L.DomEvent.addListener`, or to whatever object you pass as 4th argument.

Comment: Muhammed Naqi, thank you very much. It works. I am new in leaflet.js.